# responsive background image bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have a background image and I give the fixed scroll, I mean I create stick bar in the bottom, like in the picture below:

[image: sticky bar]

In this picture, the sticky bar in the bottom, not responsive.

this my code css:

```
.affix {
  bottom:-1px;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  background-size: 100%;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

this stick bar bottom or background color fixed scroll works fine in the desktop version and mobile version (if mobile version the screen is above the size 5,5 inch works fine but in mobile version the screen size under 4 inches the sticky bar bottom or background color green fixed scroll not responsive)

I try to change the meta tag viewport not effect, this my meta tag viewport :

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

I use bootstrap version 3.3.7

how to make the stick bar bottom or background color green fixed scroll can responsively?

Comment: Have you tried hiding the horizontal overflow of the page by using `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }` ?

Comment: i try but same sir, not effect, the button fixed bar or background color green in picture not responsive

Comment: GIve some codes pal. The code snippet would help us to identify the problem and find the solution.

Comment: @creat15 Can you show us some of your code to see how to display all that and inspect your isssue

Comment: sorry late respon, i try to clear cache browser and its work sir @JeremiahCabigting html, body { overflow-x: hidden; } thank you for help me

Comment: Okay, I will comment is as answer so you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried hiding the horizontal overflow of the page by using `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try this and see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `left: 0` and `right: 0`

```css
.affix {
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

```html
<button class='affix'>
Button
</button>
```